# How to position a web component wrt window?

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm designing a popup web component using polymer. The requirement is that I want it to be positioned exactly at the center of the browser window.

Here's the demo link - https://jsbin.com/xupowov/edit?html,output

Looks like the web component takes the direct parent as the window reference.

Isn't there a way to position it wrt window just like how usual *position: fixed* works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to position things relative to the window size, you have not use `%`  but use `wh` and `vh`

Look at this

```
     .picker {
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 2px solid silver;
        background: white;

        position: fixed;

        height: 50px;
        left: -10vw; 
        right:-10vw;
      }
```

https://jsbin.com/hugecuxebo/1/edit

now it in the center horizontal.

Comment: Giving `right` & `left` with same values to make an element centrally positioned is somewhat a hack.  What if we want to control the width also here? However accepting this answer for now.